# Customize legend pie highchart into tag div

Tags: highcharts, legend

I success create legend into div external but when click legend external don't have event show/hide series on chart.

I think problem at function event/load but I still not yet can fix.

```
        events: {
            load: function () {
                var chart = this;
                $(chart.series[0].data).each(function (i, serie) {
                    $('<li style="color: ' + serie.color + '">' + serie.name + '</li>').click(function () {
                        serie.visible ? serie.hide() : serie.show();
                    }).appendTo('#legend');
                });
            }
        }
```

This my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hoanghoang3009/oepyvgtf/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [setVisible](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setVisible)

[Forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/06wmd1Le/)

```
 events: {
            load: function () {
                var chart = this;
                $(chart.series[0].data).each(function (i, serie) {
                //console.log(serie)
                    $('<li style="color: ' + serie.color + '">' + serie.name + '</li>').click(function () {
                        serie.visible ? serie.setVisible(false) : serie.setVisible(true);
                    }).appendTo('#legend');
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: it's good answer for me. I read doc about setVisible(boolean) and series.show() and series.hide(), according to my understand it seem the same but why use setVisible() is correct and another is not correct?

Comment: as in console log error say `serie.hide is not a function` because it is dynamic in your post and `visible` is property of each series so setVisible works in my post